# BeatifulSoup How To Scrape List Objects

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the list objects from an eBay page into a list called `listings` using BeautifulSoup in Django and print the length of the list. The eBay list objects I want to scrape are all the ones with `class='sresult lvresult clearfix li'` however, my code is not working correctly as my 'listings' list is empty.

Here are the eBay list objects I am trying to scrape:

[image]

My code:

```py
url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_nkw=rolex%20submariner&_dcat=31387&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3000&_trksid=p2045573.m1684'

content = session.get(url, verify=False).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

listings = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'sresult lvresult clearfix li'})
print(len(listings))
```

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML when ebay has an API that appears to cover this stuff?

Comment: Have a look at your `soup` before you try to find things in it. Has the full page even loaded, or is the site being loaded asynchronously via ajax or another technology? If it's asynchronous, you would need a tool like selenium

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and it's working perfectly. (len(listings) == 50)

I have modified it a bit to get the status code, which is 200 from my IP address.

Can you try and see the status_code you are getting?

```
 1 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 2 import requests
 3 
 4 
 5 url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_nkw=rolex%20submariner&_dcat=31387&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3000&_trksid=p2045573.m1684'
 6 session = requests.Session()
 7 
 8 response = session.get(url, verify=False)
 9 
10 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
11 
12 listings = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'sresult lvresult clearfix li'})
13 print(len(listings))
14 print(response.status_code)
```